# get buttons with xpath with strange attribute

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

in a web page I have to select all the buttons like this :

```
<button :class="{'complete': isComplete, 'open': open}" :disabled="orderedEvents.length === 0"></button>
```

but with this xpath :

```
//button[contains(@class, 'isComplete, \'open\'')]
```

do not works!

Comment: I don't know if having a colon in an attribute name such as ":class" is really compatible with xpath. Have you tried including that character in the xpath?

Comment: yes.. but do not works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find attributes that contains colons in the name using `@*[name()]` and find it's value using `.`

```
//button[@*[starts-with(name(),':class') and contains(., \"isComplete, 'open'\")]]
```